# How can I pull in a related table?

Tags: templating, relatedto

Each of my entries has a table with budget projections.

I loop through related entries.   **But, how can I loop through and bring in the related table?**

This is my table for the entry:

```
 {% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('budgetProjections') %}
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>

            {% for column in field.settings.columns %}
                <th>{{ column.heading }}</th>
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
        {% for row in entry.budgetProjections %}
        <tr>    
            <td>{{ row.col1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col4 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col5 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col6 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col7 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col8 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col9 | number_format (0,'.',',')}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.col10 | number_format (0,'.',',') }}</td>
        </tr>          
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

This is my loop for related entries.  It creates a button and link for each related entry.  **But now, I want to pull in the related table.  How do I do that?**

```
{% set related = entry.relatedBudgetItems.all() %}
    {% if related %}

    <p> {% for item in related %}

        <a href="{{ item.getUrl() }}" class="button primary radius"><i>{{ item.title}} ({{ item.lineItem }})-  </i></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>   
    {% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you do it the same way as above just with the `item` variable instead of the `entry`

Comment: @RobinSchambach  Yep.  I forgot all about that `entry`.  Thanks.

Comment: If your question is solved, would you mind answering it with your solution?